# Identify closed polylines in ArcGIS using Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, geometry, python-parser

Running ArcGIS 10.2 here and a complete beginner with Python. I'm trying to figure out a workflow to test for closed polylines using the field calculator. Essentially what I'd like to do is to populate a specific field with "closed" or "open". This is what I've come across and if I understand it correctly, it loops through each row and checks if the first x coordinate matches the last x coordinate, if there is a match then it prints the OID.

How do I convert this to a field calculator expression?

Do I need to use an update cursor rather than search to populate my new field?

```
fc = "Boundary"  

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)  
for row in rows:  
    geom = row.shape  
    if geom.firstPoint.X == geom.lastPoint.X:  
        print row.OBJECTID  

del row, row
```

Comment: The answer is Yes. You need to use updatecursor rather than Searchcursor

Comment: I think you'd better to compare x and y. You are using field calculator. You don't need fc, searchcursor or updatecursor in field calculator

Comment: Can I do that without creating new fields with the start and end coordinates? @wetland

Comment: That's exactly what you want. You should use dictionaries to compare x and y then search OID's . https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46878/arcpy-get-list-of-adjacent-lines-per-line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [arcpy: get list of adjacent lines per line](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46878/arcpy-get-list-of-adjacent-lines-per-line)

Comment: Old-style cursors are archaic at this point -- Use DataAccess (`arcpy.da`) cursors for all your cursor needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

You don't need to use a Cursor. Right-click the Field you want to populate, then enter this info into the Field Calculator.

Answer (score 1):

I modified @klewis answer recently since I was running into an issue where some polylines had null geometry causing the field calculator to error out or give me false positives. Here is the updated code block:

```
def isClosed(geom):
    try:
        if geom.firstPoint.X == geom.lastpoint.X and geom.firstPoint.Y == geom.lastPoint.Y:
            return "1"
        else:
            return "0"
    except:
        return 'exception'
```